# retrieve target value from the list in typescript

Tags: angular

How do I get all the type values from below in angular 4?

```
console.log('rows', this._column);

rows
0: {name: "...", type: "string", ...}
1: {name: "...", type: "string", ...}
2: {name: "...", type: "datetime", ...}
3: {name: "...", type: "string", ...}
4: {name: "...", type: "number", ...}
5: {name: "...", type: "time", ...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map function for this :

```
var types = this._column.map(data => data.type)
console.log('rows', types );
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but I still get the error with this:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at DatatableComponent.set [as rows]